# Expose on OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, expose

Is there a way to get OS X 10.5-type Expose for windows, on OS X 10.7?

I've found the new "Mission Control", but I haven't figured out how to get it to show me all my windows, like before.  It shows me all my *applications*, but all the windows are piled on top of each other.  If I "swipe up" on one of the piles, the windows scoot apart a little ways, so I can see about 3 of them, but of course that means the one I'm looking for is invariably on the bottom of the pile, still.

Is there any way to get Expose for *windows* (rather than applications), like OS X used to have?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on App Expose (for some reason in preferences it's not on by default) with a 4 finger gesture which is far better than peeking at window groupings within Mission Control.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  So I can get Expose for apps-on-this-space, or one-app's-windows-everywhere.  But what I really want is all-windows-in-this-space (because grouping by Spaces is the whole point of having Spaces).  I might end up marking this as The Answer, but I'll hold out a bit further to see if somebody has a better one...